# Npm bumped version number but npmjs doesn't update

Tags: node.js, npm

Publish my first npm package earlier today. Set it to v0.0.0. I've fixed a bug and done:

```
npm version patch -m "Bumped to version %s"
```

It has now been set to `v0.0.1`

I pushed to github (with tags) but it's not updated the npm package version on npmjs.org.

Do I need to do something else? Will it update itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to manually publish the new version I'm afraid:

```
  $ npm publish
```

`npm-version` doesn't seems to push into the repository: https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-version.html

If you want to automate both process though, you can look at a specific `Grunt` task: https://github.com/geddski/grunt-release

```
  $ grunt release
```

**Edit**:

Oh in fact, there is a standalone release plugin that works with npm (No need for Grunt if you don't want to then): https://npmjs.org/package/npm-release